# Postgres Function returning no results but when the same query returns results outside function

Tags: postgresql

I am running a simple postgres function to return the count of rows. I am able to run the same query outside function with the output of raise option , but the function doesn't return any rows. I have tried different ways to produce results but unable to. Please find my function below,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.usp_spellcheck3(SearchORItems_WithPipe varchar, site varchar, lan varchar, rows_display integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (docmnt int) AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  arrSearchTerms text[];
  NewTerm varchar;
  i integer;
  AltSearch_withComma varchar;
  AltSearch_withPipe varchar;
  strDidYouMean varchar;
  dpDidYouMean double precision;
  txtDidYouMean Text;
  SearchORItems_withComma  varchar;
  SearchORItems  varchar;
  SearchORItem  varchar;
  ws varchar;
  arrSearchORItems_withComma varchar[];
BEGIN
  strDidYouMean = 'DidYouMeanRow';
  dpDidYouMean = 0.0;
  txtDidYouMean = 'DidYouMeanRow';

  ws = '''' || '%' || site || '%' || '''' ;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', ws;

  SearchORItems = REPLACE(SearchORItems_WithPipe, '|', ',');
  SELECT regexp_split_to_array(SearchORItems, ',') INTO arrSearchORItems_withComma;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', SearchORItems;

  FOR i IN 1 .. coalesce(array_upper(arrSearchORItems_withComma, 1), 1) LOOP
    IF (i = 1) THEN
      SearchORItems_withComma = '''' || arrSearchORItems_withComma[i] || '''';
    ELSE
      SearchORItems_withComma = SearchORItems_withComma||','||'''' || arrSearchORItems_withComma[i] || '''';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RAISE NOTICE '%',SearchORItems_withComma;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res_count 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT 1 FROM my_schema.features f , my_schema.documents d 
    WHERE term IN (SearchORItems_withComma) 
      AND d.docid = f.docid
      AND d.url LIKE ws
    GROUP BY f.docid, d.url) t; 

  RAISE NOTICE '%', res_count;

  SearchORItem = 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res_count
    FROM (SELECT 1 FROM my_schema.features f , my_schema.documents d 
    WHERE term IN ('||SearchORItems_withComma||') 
    AND d.docid = f.docid AND d.url LIKE ' || ws ||'
    GROUP BY f.docid, d.url) t';

  RAISE NOTICE '%',SearchORItem;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;
```

this is my query output :
NOTICE:  '%uni%'
NOTICE:  daniel,data
NOTICE:  'daniel','data'
NOTICE:  0
NOTICE:  select count(*) into res_count
  from ( select 1 from my_schema.features f , my_schema.documents d 
 where term in ('daniel','data') 
and d.docid=f.docid  and d.url like '%uni%'
 group by f.docid,d.url)t

Total query runtime: 16 ms.
0 rows retrieved.

I dont know where I'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated .. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason that nothing is returned is that you have no `RETURN` statements in your code. When a function `RETURNS TABLE` you need to explicitly put one or more `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` statements in the body of your code, with a final `RETURN` statement to indicate the end of the function. See the documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING. What exactly you want to return is not clear but likely candidates are `res_count` and `d.docid`.

Other than that, your code could use a real clean-up reducing clutter like:

```
ws := '''%' || site || '%''' ;
```

instead of:

```
ws = '''' || '%' || site || '%' || '''' ;
```

and:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res_count 
FROM my_schema.features f,
JOIN my_schema.documents d ON d.docid = f.docid
WHERE term IN (SearchORItems_withComma) 
  AND d.url LIKE ws
GROUP BY f.docid, d.url;
```

instead of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res_count 
FROM ( 
  SELECT 1 FROM my_schema.features f , my_schema.documents d 
  WHERE term IN (SearchORItems_withComma) 
    AND d.docid = f.docid
    AND d.url LIKE ws
  GROUP BY f.docid, d.url) t;
```

And you should use the assignment operator (`:=`) instead of the equality operator in any plpgsql statement that is not a SQL statement.

Comment: Hello @Patrick, Thanks for your reply .. i will change as u suggested but the problem for me is the result count (res_count) value is coming as 0, where as the same query returns a value outside function.. am i going wrong somewhere in appending quotes for IN operator??

Comment: Hi @prasadpv. I cannot give you an answer because you have not posted the structure of the tables features and documents. What strikes me as odd is that you `GROUP BY  docid, url` as this would give you multiple results (1 count for each group) into a scalar value res_count. Perhaps there is a group with 0 hits and this result is returned to you. Difficult to say. Perhaps you can make a new question with this specific problem, showing the table structures.

Comment: pls find the structure of documents and features table below..CREATE TABLE my_schema.documents
(
  docid numeric NOT NULL,
  url character varying,
  date character varying,
  language character varying,
  CONSTRAINT documents_pkey PRIMARY KEY (docid)
)CREATE TABLE my_schema.features
(
  docid double precision NOT NULL,
  term character varying NOT NULL,
  term_freq integer,
  tf numeric(10,4),
  doc_freq numeric(10,4),
  idf numeric(10,4),
  scores numeric(10,4),
  idf_okapi numeric(10,4),
  score_okapi numeric(10,4),
  d numeric(10,4),
  CONSTRAINT features_pkey PRIMARY KEY (docid, term)
)

Comment: the exact problem for me is the select (*) returns 1 row when i execute the query .. but wen i execute the function it is returning 0 rows.. this is quite surprising for me as both are same ..